# 3D game from my Magic cube

Tags: plotting

I'm a student of design. I created a [Magic cube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCK8_Bytx6I). How can I make this game with *Mathematica*?

I have already imported a mesh *.obj with 192 triangles. If anyone knows how to do this please reply.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will receive many useful responses, unless you provide more detail.